# What's the difference between Run command and commands in cmd?

Tags: autohotkey

I have the following script:

```
^!c::
Run stop
Return
```

Stop is configured to run a program via environment variables.

So if I open up cmd and type “stop” and hit enter the program opens as intended, even if I push <kbd>winkey</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> it does the same thing. However if I use the script with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>. I do not get the same result.

Why is the script doing something different?

How can I change my script to behave the same way as if it was typed into cmd or <kbd>winkey</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>?

Comment: Maybe `run cmd /c stop`

Comment: what does the /c do? also no luck

Comment: Is `stop` a batch file? What does "configured" mean?

Comment: yeah it's a bat file, I don't fully understand it but I installed some programs and changed some environment variables, and now when I type in stop it automatically finds the right file somehow.

Comment: I give up. In my experience `run` command launches anything that can be launched via `Run` dialog using the same command line.

Comment: alright haha thanks for your help anyway :)

Comment: The environment variables in the autohotkey script may be different than running it from cmd or from the Run dialog. Also one important thing to check is the CWD (current working directory). If the CWD is different than the stop program or batch file, it may cause things to break too.

Comment: @PressingOnAlways can I set the CWD in the run command? or do I have to move the .ahk file to do that?

Comment: @Aequitas - https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/SetWorkingDir.htm

Comment: @PressingOnAlways with the /k that Schneyer mentioned I can now see that when I run "stop" in cmd I get the message: _The system cannot find the path specified._ So I changed the workingdir to the same as the other cmd but it doesn't work still for some reason. [See picture](http://i.imgur.com/nNyk58W.png). If I try manually typing in "stop" into the cmd opened by AHK it still doesn't work.

Comment: I'm now using: `RunAs, user, password
 SetWorkingDir, C:\Users\user
 run, P:\folder\stop.bat`
and it still doesn't run the batch, but when I hit my hotkeys, I get an AHK error saying it couldn't find the path specified. I have other hotkeys that launch .exe files in the same folder as stop.bat which work fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Simple**:

```
run, %comspec% /c stop
```

Or if this doesn't work you could just **start a cmd window and send it directly**

```
run, %comspec% /k
WinWait, %comspec%
WinActivate
Send stop{Enter}
```

`/c` tells the console window to close after execution, `/k` lets it stay open

or you could use an **COM object** and even get the output.

```
objShell := ComObjCreate("WScript.Shell")
objExec := objShell.Exec(ComSpec " /c stop")

strStdOut := ""
while, !objExec.StdOut.AtEndOfStream
{
    strStdOut := objExec.StdOut.ReadAll()
}
```

---

Update: 
**Without the run command at all:**

```
SetTitleMatchMode, 2

send #r

WinWait, TITLE_OF_THE_RUN_WINDOW
WinActivate

send cmd{Enter}

WinWait, cmd.exe
WinActivate

WinGetTitle, title
Send stop{Enter}

WinWait, %title%,,, stop
WinClose,
```

`TITLE_OF_THE_RUN_WINDOW` replace this with the title of the window, which opens on Win+r. A windows cmd window has the command in its title while it gets executed. So we save the title of the command window, and wait for it to drop the command ("stop") and close it then.

UPDATE: Cmd window close added to solution 4

Comment: I get a "The system cannot find the path specified"

Comment: Try i with "cmd.exe" instead of the Comspec variable

Comment: yep that launches it fine, and if I type "stop" in there then it launches my bat file

Comment: Updated anser and added one more way to do it.

Comment: That last one worked when I replaced the winwait and winactivate with a sleep of 100ms. Is there anyway to close cmd when it's finished?

Comment: Update to 4th solution: Close window after execution